# Cucumber.CompositeCucumberException Error "No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH."

Tags: java, android, dependencies, cucumber, android-espresso

I tried to implement Cucumber to my Android project and also I use Espresso. But I got an error, message: `Cucumber.CompositeCucumberException Error "No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH."`.
I can't solve this problem.

Please Can you help me?

I use Espresso and Android Studio.

**File Structure**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o42Up.png)

**My Instumantation class**

```
public class Instumentation extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    private final CucumberInstrumentationCore instrumentationCore = new CucumberInstrumentationCore(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        instrumentationCore.create(bundle);
        super.onCreate(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        waitForIdleSync();
        instrumentationCore.start();
    }
}
```

Runner file

```
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:" + Runner.REPORT_PATH + "cucumber-html-report",
                "pretty:" + Runner.REPORT_PATH + "cucumber-report.json",
                "junit:" + Runner.REPORT_PATH + "cucumber.xml"
        },
        features = "features",
        tags = "@shortSanity")
public class Runner {

    public static final String REPORT_PATH = "data/data/" + com.example.loginexample.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/cucumber-reports/";

}
```

App build grandle

I think about dependency. I searched on StackOverFlow. Everyone said that but no matter what I try

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.loginexample"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testApplicationId "com.example.loginexample.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.loginexample.Instumentation"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    //Not change
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.5'

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:2.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.5'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:7.12.1'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-core:7.12.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.12.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
}
```

Project build grandle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And Error detail:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.cucumber.core.exception.CompositeCucumberException: There were 2 exceptions. The details are in the stacktrace below.
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.getThrowable(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:57)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getThrowable(CucumberExecutionContext.java:109)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:155)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:78)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
    Suppressed: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:39)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:33)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.createRunner(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:43)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.get(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:35)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:35)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getRunner(CucumberExecutionContext.java:141)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runBeforeAllHooks(CucumberExecutionContext.java:93)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runFeatures$6(CucumberExecutionContext.java:147)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.execute(CucumberExecutionContext.java:163)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:146)
        ... 3 more
    Suppressed: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:39)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:33)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.createRunner(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:43)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.get(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:35)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:35)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getRunner(CucumberExecutionContext.java:141)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runAfterAllHooks(CucumberExecutionContext.java:98)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.execute(CucumberExecutionContext.java:163)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:151)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: And also My ide  android 2022.2